# Substitution in Normal Distribution integral calculation

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, substitution

The pdf of the normal distribution is:
$$ \phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}\left( \tfrac{x - \mu}{\sigma} \right)^2}.$$

Now assume $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

I am interested in $\mathbb{E}[Z^2]$ for $Z = \dfrac{x- \mu}{\sigma}$. For this purpose, I first write:
$$ \phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\tfrac{1}{2} z^2}$$

and then have $$ \mathbb{E}[Z^2] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} z^2 e^{-\tfrac{1}{2} z^2} dz  \qquad (1)$$

But apparently the correct answer is:
$$ \mathbb{E}[Z^2] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \sigma\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} z^2 e^{-\tfrac{1}{2} z^2} dz. \qquad (2) $$

I can see that in order to have $\sigma$ in the beginning, at (1) I need to use $dx$ (instead of $dz$) and then we have $\sigma dz =  dx$. But, once we write the pdf of $z$ as $\phi(z)$ isn't the change in $z$ anymore? I am confused.

Edit: I think if I instead write down the formula $\mathbb{E}[((X-\mu)/\sigma)^2]$ then I end up at the correct answer. Maybe I am missing an important calculus property at (1).

Comment: Did you miss $1/\sigma^2$ in the exponential exponent in $\phi(z)$?

Comment: @user58955 no I dont think so

Comment: There's a problem with density function of $Z$. $Z$ should be normal with mean $0$, variance $1$. And that's exactly that "missing" $\sigma$

Comment: @DominikKutek from the normal distribution of x to z how can I obtain the true derivaiton?

Comment: Let me explain it in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and let $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$.

Then the density function of $X$ (call it $f_X$) is equal to: $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$. Since $Z$ is just a translated and scalled $X$, will have density, too ( call it $f_Z $ ).

As I see, you have problem in one point:

It is true, that for $\omega \in \Omega$ we have $Z(\omega) = \frac{X(\omega) - \mu}{\sigma}$, but not that $f_Z(x) = f_X(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$. Densities do not work this way. In fact you can derive the density of $Z$ by looking at $CDF$ and then differentiate it (as long as it will be piecewise continuosly differentiable or so) or try to substitute in integrals to get from $f_X$ to $f_Z$ like this:

Let $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ be borel set and denote $\nu_Z, \nu_X$ the distributions of $Z,X$ respectivelly.

Then we have $\nu_Z(A) = \mathbb P(Z \in A) = \mathbb P(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \in A) = \mathbb P(X \in \sigma A + \mu) = \nu_X(\sigma A + \mu) $, where $\sigma A + \mu = \{ \sigma a + \mu : a \in A \}$

Now, we have $$\nu_X(\sigma A + \mu) = \int_{\sigma A + \mu} f_X(x)dx $$

And here, doing substitution $z = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, we get $dz = \frac{1}{\sigma} dx$ (that is the $\sigma$ u were missing). and from set $\sigma A + \mu$ we get back to just $A$, getting:

$$ \nu_X(\sigma A + \mu) = \int_A \sigma f_X(\sigma z + \mu) dz, $$

but $\nu_X(\sigma A + \mu) = \nu_Z(A)$, so we get the distribution of $Z$ which is:

$$\nu_Z(A) = \int_A \sigma f_X(\sigma z + \mu) dz.$$

**So the density of $Z$** is $f_Z(z) = \sigma f_X(\sigma z + \mu) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp( - \frac{z^2}{2}).$

If you're interested in approach with $CDF$ it goes like this: let $F_X, F_Z$ be CDF of $X,Z$ respectivelly, then:

$F_Z(t) = \mathbb P(Z \le t) = \mathbb P(X \le \sigma t + \mu) = F_X(\sigma t + \mu)$

Since $F_X$ was differentiable continuosly and function $t \to \sigma t + \mu$ is continuosuly differentiable, so is their superposition, so to get density of $Z$ just differentiate $F_Z$ getting:

$f_Z(t) = \frac{d}{dt} F_Z(t) = \frac{d}{dt} F_X(\sigma t + \mu) =  F_X'(\sigma t + \mu) \cdot \sigma = f_X(\sigma t + \mu) \cdot \sigma$

(in this case it is simplier and generally (at least for me) it is simplier

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't follow it, but going to read once again!

But, is it still valid if I just calculate $\mathbb{E}[((X-\mu)/\sigma)^2]$ instead of substituting z to derive a new pdf?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\mathbb E[(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma})^2] = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \mathbb E[(X-\mu)^2] = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} Var(X) = 1$. As you see it is so much simplier, but I've just wanted to explain how to get the density because as I saw, you had problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a very helpful Wikipedia article, easy to understand: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability